# Strange behaviour of enumerate with cython and python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, cython, enumerate

We have a bunch of code to port in python3 and we are facing a very strange behaviour with enumerate.

```
cdef char **c_argv
c_argv = <char**>malloc(sizeof(char*) * len(args))
for idx, s in enumerate(args):
    if bytes != str:
        s = s.encode('utf-8')
    c_argv[idx] = s
```

With python2, we will see all the argv in c_argv, whereas in python3 we see only one ... To note, if we write the for in a "pythonic" way without enumerate :

```
for i in args:
```

This doesn't work neither.

Here is the full reproducer of our tests :

**test_enumerate.pyx**

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from libc.string cimport const_char

def test_enumerate(args):
    cdef char **c_argv
    c_argv = <char**>malloc(sizeof(char*) * len(args))
    for idx, s in enumerate(args):
        if bytes != str:
            s = s.encode('utf-8')
        c_argv[idx] = s

    for i in range(len(args)):
        print("Set by enumerate",c_argv[i])        
    free(c_argv)

def test_loop_obj(args):
    cdef char **c_argv
    c_argv = <char**>malloc(sizeof(char*) * len(args))
    idx=0
    for s in (args):
        if bytes != str:
            s = s.encode('utf-8')
        c_argv[idx] = s
        idx = idx+1
        
    for i in range(len(args)):
        print("Set by loop on objects",c_argv[i])        
    free(c_argv)

def test_loop(args):
    cdef char **c_argv
    c_argv = <char**>malloc(sizeof(char*) * len(args))
    for i in range(len(args)):
        if bytes != str:
            args[i] = args[i].encode('utf-8')
        c_argv[i] = args[i]

    for i in range(len(args)):
        print("Set by loop on index",c_argv[i])        
    free(c_argv)
```

**test.py**

```
from test_enumerate import test_enumerate, test_loop_obj, test_loop
test_enumerate(['salut','tu','vas','bien'])
test_loop_obj(['salut','tu','vas','bien'])
test_loop(['salut','tu','vas','bien'])
```

**setup.py:**

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("test_enumerate.pyx")
)
```

We compile it with :

```
python/python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

And here is the output illustrating our problem :

```
$ python test.py
('Set by enumerate', 'salut')
('Set by enumerate', 'tu')
('Set by enumerate', 'vas')
('Set by enumerate', 'bien')
('Set by loop on objects', 'salut')
('Set by loop on objects', 'tu')
('Set by loop on objects', 'vas')
('Set by loop on objects', 'bien')
('Set by loop on index', 'salut')
('Set by loop on index', 'tu')
('Set by loop on index', 'vas')
('Set by loop on index', 'bien')
```

```
$ python3 test.py
('Set by enumerate', b'bien')
('Set by enumerate', b'bien')
('Set by enumerate', b'bien')
('Set by enumerate', b'bien')
('Set by loop on objects', b'bien')
('Set by loop on objects', b'bien')
('Set by loop on objects', b'bien')
('Set by loop on objects', b'bien')
('Set by loop on index', b'salut')
('Set by loop on index', b'tu')
('Set by loop on index', b'vas')
('Set by loop on index', b'bien')
```

Someone could explain what we are missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

```
c_argv[idx] = s
```

This sets `c_argv[idx]` to be a pointer into the data of `s`. The pointer is only valid while `s` still exists.

```
s = s.encode('utf-8')
```

If this line happens then a new encoded `s` is created, causing the previous encoded `s` to be decrefed and thus probably freed.

Basically, don't mess around with c-pointers unless you understand (and can control) their lifetime.